# Django: Is there a simple way to query "Model.field starts with a digit (0 to 9)"?

Tags: django, django-forms

Hopefully simple Django question here. Short of using a long chain of Q objects OR'd together, is there an simple way to query something like:

```
item = Item.objects.filter(name__startswith='[a digit here]')
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can user [regex to query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#regex):

```
item = Item.objects.filter(name__regex=r'^\d[\w\d _-]+')
```

You will need to adjust the regex depending on what you are querying.

Comment: Thanks, didn't even know that existed!

Comment: Yea, it's handy - I went a while with out knowing it too :)